Setting a predefinite scalebox for the math mode in text-lines
When I write fractions during a text-line (for example: [...] as we can see \(\frac{3}{4} < \frac{10}{3}\) [...]) the fractions are too little, and I always have to scalebox them with the command \scalebox{1.2}{\( ... \)}.
The operation can be tedious, and hence I ask: is there a way to set this predefinite command for all the fractions in text-lines writing? I ask explicitly for the fractions since when scaleboxing pure numbers the result is aesthetically unpleasing. Scaleboxing the writing \(2 + \frac{1}{n}\) would result in a too much big \(2\).
Yes, everyone has its manias... I didn't find how to proceed, if this is possible. I'm started to think that this isn't possible though.
Thank you!

don't use \scalebox. perhaps you want \dfrac instead of \frac but the fractions are not "too little" they are designed to fit within the line spacing of the paragraph, if you do not want that it is more normal to use display math \[...\] not inline math \(...\)

The whole design of inline math (\(..\) or $...$) is to set the math within the existing line spacing of the paragraph, so fractions are not "too little" they are "as large as possible within the design constraints".
That said, you can use \dfrac to force display style fractions, but then as seen in the second example this disturbs the line spacing, and in such cases it is normally better to use display math (\[..\]) as shown in the third example.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
\(1+ \frac{3}{4} < 2+ \frac{10}{3}\)
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.

\bigskip

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
\(1+ \dfrac{3}{4} < 2+ \dfrac{10}{3}\)
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.

\bigskip

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
\[1+ \frac{3}{4} < 2+ \frac{10}{3}\]
Red yellow blue green black white pink orange.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.



\end{document}


You decide which one looks better. I have no doubt that it's the top one, with no scaling.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\scaledfrac}[2]{%
  \scalebox{1.2}{$\frac{#1}{#2}$}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{No scaling}

Some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
\(2+\frac{1}{n}\)
some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text 
\(\frac{3}{4} < \frac{10}{3}\)
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 

\section*{With scaling}

Some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
\(2+\scaledfrac{1}{n}\)
some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text 
\(\scaledfrac{3}{4} < \scaledfrac{10}{3}\)
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 
some nonsense text some nonsense text some nonsense text 

\end{document}


